How to grant user superuser privileges in PieCloudDB
Currently, I'm facing a "permission denied" error on PieCloudDB Database when I try to query certain system tables through the web interface. How do I grant my user superuser privileges to query all database objects?

By default, users created via PieCloudDB cloud platform are normal users. To upgrade a user to a database superuser, you can follow these steps:

Find your warehouse's ID in the virtual data warehouse page, e.g. cl0xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

On the server hosting PieCloudDB, run the command kubectl exec -it pdb-qd-cl0xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-0 -n openpie-clusters -- psql -c "alter role <yourrolename> superuser"


